# how to refer to HTML element using this in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new to using jQuery... I'm trying to add a dropdown menu, which appears on clicking the "edit" **using this** and **without using the id or class**... it should hide on blur()...

**css:**

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="col-2 col-2-s edit dropdown">
    <span>
        <a href="javascript:dropdown()">Edit</a>
    </span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">edit list items</div>
</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
function dropdown() {
    $(this).parent.siblings().show();
}
```

**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JS in your HTML should be an `onclick` not the `href` attribute. Then you can pass the element as the argument to the function. And you left off the `()` in `.parent()`

```js
function dropdown(el) {
    $(el).parent().siblings().show();
}
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-2 col-2-s edit dropdown">
    <span>
        <a onclick="dropdown(this)">Edit</a>
    </span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">edit list items</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onclick attriute, use jQuery binding.

Something like this should work:

```
<div class="col-2 col-2-s edit dropdown">
    <span>
        <a data-target="show-siblings">Edit</a>
    </span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">edit list items</div>
</div>

$('a[data-target="show-siblings"]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().show();
});
```

I user the `data-target` attribute because I'm assuming you'll have more than one `a` element on you html.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like :

```
<div class="col-2 col-2-s edit dropdown">
    <span>
    <script>
    function dropdown(e) {
        $(e).parent().siblings().css("display","block");
    }
    </script>
        <a  href="#" onclick="dropdown(this)">Edit</a>
    </span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">edit list items</div>
</div>
```